# JavaScript Neutralizes after Ajax Action

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, youtube-api

i am trying to run a script on a youtube video appears after ajax action to control it but as soon ajax load the youtube iframe it come but without any javascript affection :

> with this code it works :

```
<iframe id="player" width="80%" height="80%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/sREemKFBJX8?enablejsapi=1&autoplay=1"></iframe>
<script>
    var player;
    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
            events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
            }
        });
    }
    function onPlayerReady(event) {
        document.getElementById('player').style.borderColor = '#FF6D00';
    }
    function changeBorderColor(playerStatus) {
        var color;
        if (playerStatus == -1) {
          color = "#37474F"; // unstarted = gray
        } else if (playerStatus == 0) {
          color = "#FFFF00"; // ended = yellow
        } else if (playerStatus == 1) {
          color = "#33691E"; // playing = green
        } else if (playerStatus == 2) {
          color = "#DD2C00"; // paused = red
        } else if (playerStatus == 3) {
          color = "#AA00FF"; // buffering = purple
        } else if (playerStatus == 5) {
          color = "#FF6DOO"; // video cued = orange
        }
        if (color) {
          document.getElementById('player').style.borderColor = color;
        }
    }
    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        changeBorderColor(event.data);
    }
</script>
<script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
```

but when i use Ajax the javascript stop working :

> index.php

```
<div id="main_div"></div>
<button class="button">Show Player</button>
<script>
$(document).on('click', '.button', function (){
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    try{
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }catch(e){
        xmlhttp = false;
    }
} else {
    // code for IE6, IE5
    try{
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }catch(e){
        xmlhttp = false;
    }
}   
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("main_div").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
};  
xmlhttp.open("GET", "ajax/load_player.php", true);
xmlhttp.send(null);
});
</script>
<script>
    var player;
    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
            events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
            }
        });
    }
    function onPlayerReady(event) {
        document.getElementById('player').style.borderColor = '#FF6D00';
    }
    function changeBorderColor(playerStatus) {
        var color;
        if (playerStatus == -1) {
          color = "#37474F"; // unstarted = gray
        } else if (playerStatus == 0) {
          color = "#FFFF00"; // ended = yellow
        } else if (playerStatus == 1) {
          color = "#33691E"; // playing = green
        } else if (playerStatus == 2) {
          color = "#DD2C00"; // paused = red
        } else if (playerStatus == 3) {
          color = "#AA00FF"; // buffering = purple
        } else if (playerStatus == 5) {
          color = "#FF6DOO"; // video cued = orange
        }
        if (color) {
          document.getElementById('player').style.borderColor = color;
        }
    }
    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        changeBorderColor(event.data);
    }
</script>
<script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
```

> load_player.php

```
<iframe id="player" width="80%" height="80%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/sREemKFBJX8?enablejsapi=1&autoplay=1"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the api is loaded and the onYouTubeIframeAPIReady event with code for instanciating the player is called before the actual iframe is present. In the following fiddle i changed your code so that also creating the player instance is bound to the button click (so that the instance is created AFTER the iframe is loaded and AFTER the api is loaded)

onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() :

```
var ytready = false;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    ytready = true;
}
```

after the Ajax call:

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("main_div").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                player = new YT.Player('player', {
                events: {
                    'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                    'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
                }
            });
        }
    };
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0y7sedpx/3/

Comment: thanks @Ben for your answer but i tryed it .. it did not work ... and that's very strange i work with Ajax a lot but this small Problem stucks ..

Comment: Error in event handler for (unknown): TypeError: Cannot read property 'command' of undefined
    at chrome-extension://fhplmmllnpjjlncfjpbbpjadoeijkogc/js/hooks/content.js:1:228

Comment: but not always @Ben

Comment: I only got errors cause $(document) was not defined. After i added jquery as external resource i dont get any errors at all and the video plays fine (tested in chrome and firefox)

Comment: here's a fiddle link with the code that works for me (it's not working out of the box since there is no load_player.php) https://jsfiddle.net/0y7sedpx/1/

Comment: it loads the video but without Api colors affection ? did you see the colors affections ?

Comment: it loads the video but without Api colors affection ? did you see the colors affections ? @Ben

Comment: It seems to be a timing problem. I changed the onYouTubeIframeAPIReady code so that the new play instance is not created immideatly but after 5 seconds. When  i hit the "show player" button within those 5 seconds it works afterwards with the border colors..

Comment: I updated the fiddle so far (although it's not a final solution yet)

Comment: ok i updated the fiddle to my final solution .. see my original answer for details

Comment: you are the best @Ben thank you v.much i appreciate this help !

Comment: glad i could help